# absolute child in parent is not filling parent background correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create custom tab component and i have css/render problem.

Here is the link to jsBIN : https://gist.github.com/FluksikartonGOD/351d649d4876059f88fd7bc63abfa8e0

As you can see there is very little red where the border radius is applied. how to fix that?

```css
body {
 background-color: red;
}
.switch-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto
}
.switch-container span {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
    user-select: none;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.switch-container span.active {
   color: blue
}
.switch-container span:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
}
.switch-container:before {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 34px;
    background-color: white;
    will-change: transform;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in;
}
.switch-container.left-side:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.switch-container.right-side:before {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="switch-container">
                <span class="item flex-item text-center active" target="switchItem1">Something 1</span>
                <span class="item flex-item text-center" target="switchItem2">Something 2</span>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share some run-able code

Comment: I have shared the code inside link there is a link to jsBin and you can edit and see the whole code of it

Comment: Remove overflow:hidden to solve that issue.

Comment: @Himanshu Gupta still not working try it

Comment: I'd say that's because you use the pseudo-element before. When i set some style on the element itselft, the result is much cleaner.

Comment: so you say to add element with the style of before and not to use before. Why this is issue bug to the css or what

Comment: It's more simple to just style the elements. When you can avoid adding pseudo-elements, it's more simple. By just adding the `background-color` and `border-radius` and deleting the pseudo element, you get a cleaner result. You still get a little bit of red, but i think it is aliasing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find my answer below as I have used box-shadow for border. Because border is not so smooth with radius. If you also want to use shadow, add another value in box-shadow with comma separated.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.switch-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white inset;
  border-radius: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.switch-container span {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.switch-container span.active {
  color: blue
}

.switch-container span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 34px;
  background-color: white;
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in;
}

.switch-container.left-side:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.switch-container.right-side:before {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-container">
  <span class="item flex-item text-center active" target="switchItem1">Something 1</span>
  <span class="item flex-item text-center" target="switchItem2">Something 2</span>
</div>
```